# tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy() does not output what it should output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to train a classifier CNN with 3 classes. I am trying to troubleshoot my loss function. I am testing `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()` and `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy().numpy()`. I am following the standealone usage guide from [the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/categorical_crossentropy).

I think that I am not getting the proper outputs that I should be.
When I input `y_true=[0.,1.,0.]` and `y_pred=[1.,0.,0.]` I expect a loss of infinity (output in the program: `nan`). However, the output I receive is `16.118095`. When the classification aligns with the label (i.e. `y_true=[1.,0.,0.]` and `y_pred=[1.,0.,0.]`) the output is `1.192093e-07`, even though I would expect a perfect 0.

I am really perplexed by this behavior. Similarly, with the 1 long vector case: `y_true=[1.]` and `y_pred=[0.]` the loss is `16.118095`, and likewise when the classification aligns `y_true=[1.]` and `y_pred=[1.]` I receive `1.192093e-07` and `y_true=[0.]` and `y_pred=[0.]` the result is `nan`.

I think that summarizing the results I get, the results I expect, and the values I am inputting into the loss functions would make things more readable so I will do that below:

| `y_true` | `y_pred` | Actual Output | What I Expect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[0.,1.,0.]` | `[1.,0.,0.]` | 16.118095 | `nan` or infinity |
| `[1.,0.,0.]` | `[1.,0.,0.]` | 1.192093e-07 | True 0 |
| `[0.,1.]` | `[1.,0.]` | 16.118095 | `nan` or infinity |
| `[1.,0.]` | `[1.,0.]` | 1.192093e-07 | True 0 |
| `[1.]` | `[0]` | `nan` or infinity | `nan` or infinity |
| `[1.]` | `[1.]` | 1.192093e-07 | True 0 |

I am sorry if this is a trivial question, but I really don't know why I am getting the results that I am getting. I think something is wrong because I am only getting 16 and not infinity, but if nothing is going wrong I'd like the reassurance. If I am wrong, I would really appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` applies a small offset (`1e-7`) to `y_pred` when it's equal to one or zero, that's why in your case you don't see the output that you expect.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=False):
    if clip == True:
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    return - tf.experimental.numpy.nansum(y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred))

y_true = [0., 1., 0.]
y_pred = [1., 0., 0.]

print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
# 16.118095

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=True).numpy())
# 16.118095

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=False).numpy())
# inf

y_true = [1., 0., 0.]
y_pred = [1., 0., 0.]

print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
# 1.1920929e-07

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=True).numpy())
# 1.1920929e-07

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=False).numpy())
# -0.0

y_true = [0., 1., 0.]
y_pred = [0.05, 0.95, 0.]

print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
# 0.051293306

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=True).numpy())
# 0.051293306

print(categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, clip=False).numpy())
# 0.051293306
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough response! If I am understanding correctly, the numerical differences are because of the offset tensorflow automatically includes and I am getting the results that I should be getting?

Comment: Yes that's correct, there is nothing wrong with your code and the results that you are getting are as expected.